# Mocha expect does not behave as expected

Tags: mocha.js

Just noticed something which I find a little strange, the following passes

```
expect(driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.contain('Home/Selection/CH')
```

even though the current URL is [www.someurl.com/Home/Selection/XX](http://www.someurl.com/Home/Selection/XX) and there does not contain Home/Selection/CH

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it:

```js
expect(driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.contain('Home/Selection/CH')
```